# Access npm task parameters from javascript files

Tags: node.js, npm, process

In my package.json I have a script like so:

```
"start": "runsMyApp --value=tt && node -e 'console.log(process.env)'"
```

When I run my script

```
npm run start
```

I can see my variable logged:

```
npm_config_value: 'tt'
```

My question is, can I access the `npm_config_value` from `process.env.npm_config_value` in my js files as I can do with `process.env.NODE_ENV` ?

I can't manage to pick its value, I have also tried with `process.npm_config_value` without success...

Any hints on this?

Comment: What *is* `runsMyApp`? Which side of that is logging the value (note you can `node -p 'process.env'`)? Where are you adding `process[.env].npm_config_value`?

Comment: I just want to pass a parameter to some npm task and have it available in my javascript  files as `if(process.env.value === tt) {...}` 
I just had a look at npm cross-env but I can't achieve what I want.

Comment: If you mean you want to accept arguments to `runsMyApp` like `--value=tt` and it's a JS script, then look at `process.argv`. If you mean you want to set environment variables then `cross-env` certainly *does* work. Please [edit] to clarify what's actually going on.